# card dealer java gui

Tags: java, user-interface

I have to create a GUI application that randomly selects a card from the deck and displays it each time the user clicks on it. After a card is selected it is removed from the deck and can no longer be used. A message should be displayed when there are no more cards left in the deck. I am completely lost and any help would be appreciated.

I forgot to mention that I have pictures to go with each of the cards as well. How would I associate the ID of the card with the picture?

Comment: Did you tried anything yourself?

Comment: make a Class Card [like this](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes4/source/Card.java) once you finish this step **A SIMILAR CLASS AS PER YOUR NEEDS** , update the post

Comment: I can do all the things like creating panels and adding things to them, I just have a problem figuring out how to start. This is probably my worst subject. I just need help figuring out where to start and what to include etc. I can do the rest by myself

Comment: once above step [my comment for Card class] is done refer http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes4/source/Deck.java and make an update to this post

Comment: Ok I am new to this how do I update post?

Comment: once u finish ur basic Card/Desk structure click on **edit** button below your post

Comment: Ok this is a GUI. Also, in the array you created in your example you don't specify a data type. You say private Card[] deck;

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't expect anyone to do your homework for you but there are at least a couple of things here you could look up to get you started.

I'm also a beginner programmer starting out in Java and my first project involved cards and random card drawing. I stored the deck of cards in a **two dimensional array** and  picked them out randomly by generating two random numbers with **Math.Random**, one for the suit and one for the card in that suit.

I'm sure there are much, MUCH better ways of solving this but this was the easiest way for me at the time and seemed to do the job.

Comment: This is a good answer, in that you provide a suggestion of where to start and some of the things to think about.  However note that this strategy has a problem - you can't easily remove cards.  Even if you set the field in the array to `null`, that slows down your program as you draw more and more cards (because you have to try again if you draw a card you've already drawn).  This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample) may give you some ideas for how to improve your solution - the key phrase is "without replacement".

Comment: Great this was really helpful! Thanks at least I know where to start. That is the problem for me and I don't expect anyone to do my homework but I just need help starting and your way seems like a good way to me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the other comment about removing the cards, that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

One way this could be done is to make a list of IDs of cards. For example, you could put the 1 of hearts as ID 0, put 1 of aces as ID 1, and so on. Then, you could use the `Math.Random` class to chose one ID out of the list of IDs whenever the button is clicked, and display the card. Once the card is displayed, remove the ID from the deck so it will not be chosen again.

Comment: Ok thank you. This sounds like a good idea as well. I forgot to mention that I have pictures to go with each of the cards as well.